# Why HashMap method returns null object reference?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, hashmap

I've tried to make a `HashMap` method to get SQLite database data, but when I call the method it returns `null` reference that made my Android app stop working.

This my code:

### HashMap method:

```
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("position", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("level", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("uid", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(6));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return user;
}
```

and this how I call the method in other class

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
HashMap<String,String> userDetail= db.getUserDetails();
int userLevel = Integer.parseInt(userDetail.get("level").toString());
```

anyway I use a tutorial reference to make this and merge with my own needs.

Comment: Perhaps `cursor.getString(3)` returns null, which means `userDetail.get("level")` would return null.

Comment: It is not possible for `user` to be null and therefore, not possible for `getUserDetails` to return null.  There are only 3 results for that method.  1, it returns an empty `HashMap<string, string>` because the login table is empty, 2.  it returns a populated `HashMap` 3.  it crashes.

Comment: I'm sorry i mean null object reference ... i will edit the title asap

Comment: A null object reference occurs when you try to reference a null object!  A method cannot return a "null object reference".  @Eran is probably correct.  use the debugger to watch what happens.  I also think you should complete some basic Java tutorials.

Comment: I don't add any value to the table ... is that will return null? ... i tought a empty table will just return empty string ..

Comment: `if(cursor.getCount() > 0)`  Since you return a `new HashMap`, the `String` values will all be null.

Comment: I really don't understand why you don't just use the debugger and step through your code.  You would find the problem in less time than it took to write your question.

Comment: i'm sorry still new at android, i dont fully understand what in the debugger generate mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `user` object if the user exists in the database, otherwise return `null` and check if the `user` is `null`

```
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String,String> user = null;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    try {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor != null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("position", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("level", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("uid", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(6));
    }
}
} finally {
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}

    return user;
}
```

Then

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
HashMap<String,String> userDetail= db.getUserDetails();
if (userDetail != null) {
  String level = userDetail.get("level");
  if (level != null){
    try {
      int userLevel = Integer.parseInt(level);
    } catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference in your answer and OP's question. What he actually asked is why 'level' returns null?

Comment: Because he has put `null` value. This code teaches OP how to use exception handling and prevent NPE to make application working, also how an when use `null` OR.

Comment: @Apurva Because as he states in his comment, the login table is empty.  Therefore he returns an emtpy `HashMap`

Comment: @Simon What is the reason to return an empty hashmap when there's no record in db?

Comment: @RomanC  Read the code, the initialisation for each `String` in user is inside an if statement, `if(cursor.getCount() > 0)`

Comment: @Simon You didn't answer my question, also *initialisation* spells as initialization. I have read the question before I've got this answer.

Comment: @Roman.  Initialization is American, Initlialisation is correct in most forms of English and since  this is an international forum, I take offence at your arrogance,  Since the table is empty, this is the execution flow.   `HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return user;`

Comment: @RomanC BTW, I upvoted you since your solution is correct and will solve the OPs problem.  I have no idea why you chose to argue with me and now regret the vote.

Comment: @Roman C I'm sorry what is the point declare 'HashMap<String,String> user = null;' instead of 'HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();' .... after learn how to use debugger as Simon said the user is return 0 not null , Any way ur solution is work on  my code so thanks for teaching me how to handle NPE and i vote for u AND thanks for Simon too ... sorry i still can't up vote up the comment

Comment: @ibrahimsaputra It's common way to determine if an object has been properly created by a method.  You first set the object to null, then initialise it in the method.  Is the initialisation fails, for example because your database is empty, you return the null.  The caller of the method can check for a null return to know whether the method succeeded or not, then call some other method, e.g. `createNewUser()`

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the great explanation of my ideas, because I prefer to speak in Java and I even didn't know the word is a synonym. I have asked you a simple question for your confirmation to make me sure you agree with the answer and could confirm it to OP. As you did at the last comment. I have nothing with arrogance or offense. It is a normal communication style I don't know why did you react like that. I have also +1 your comment if you didn't note it. I don't know, may be you had a bad mood, hence you behave like that. Forget it, and thank you again and your +1 if it has the power yet.

Comment: @RomanC I see now.  I did not mean that he **should** return an empty HashMap, your answer is the correct way to do it, I was explaining **why** he was returning an empty HashMap, and therefore why he caused a null reference exception.